# Local production and development works, but heroku only using express server calls

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, npm

**edit. heroku is only getting or using my server file, still trying to figure out how to have it use the client as well.'**

I am trying to get my first app that I built on my own up on heroku.  I am not done with it, but the basics of it work fine, and the version of it so far works fine when I run `npm run dev.`, and use production from my localhost.

When I try to push it to heroku however, I get **Cannot GET /** on the page, and when I check some other paths i've identified in express, I get the raw json data back.  The problem is looking like my client might be getting ignored, so I'm sure I'm messing up somewhere in my package.json.

I started this with create-react-app, and the client and server both have their own packages.

*file pathing in server.js (some code edited out for viewability.  Commenting out joining file path does nothing, so that is probably not the issue):*

```
const path = require('path');
// const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, './client/build'); //maybe this?
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var {mongoose} = require('./server/db/mongoose');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
//app.use('/', express.static(`${__dirname}/client/build`)); //or this?

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

*server package.JSON (not sure if i need the start script here.):*

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

*client package.JSON (I have already run npm run-script build):*

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/"
}
```

*Heroku build log (which says success, but error in npm_config_loglevel):*

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  9.3.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 9.3.0...
       Downloading and installing node 9.3.0...
       Using default npm version: 5.5.1
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       up to date in 0.596s
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 19.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v11
       (site) deployed to Heroku
```

[Here](https://github.com/DORRITO/MCMTAC) is the link to the github file if it's easier for you to see the packages there in relation to the file paths.

Again, this is unfinished but **fully working when using `npm run dev and a local production server`**. Heroku is working, but not as it should.  I am using node v9.3, mongo v3.2.  I had a previous response saying it might be fixed by adding a heroku postbuild to the server package.json, but my heroku pushes were rejected when I tried that method.

This is a longer question, but I am truly stuck so I really appreciate the help, and hope to one day return the favor to other new folks in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working as you expect is due to the following:

1. You are missing a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile).
2. If a Procfile is not present, then Heroku will default to `npm run start` as stated [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type). Which is why it is only picking up your `server.js`.
3. Heroku will only install production dependencies which is anything defined under `dependencies` section in `package.json`. You can override this by following the directions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies), but generally you don't use dev related dependencies in production.

Comment: Thank you for the Procfile knowledge!  That was good to learn, but did not apply in this case. 
I appreciate the attempt to help me with these 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
"install": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
```

added to the scripts in the server package.json got everything to work.

Also, if anyone else has this issue, make sure you have mlab mongodb on your heroku page as an addon.